# How to assign a custom post title to be the post ID?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to assign a custom post title name to the post ID upon submitting an ACF form?
I'm trying to do this because I don't use the custom post title, instead I just want it to be the post ID.
I'm using the "twentythirteen" template.

Here's what I have to assign the post title from ACF fields in the functions.php:

```
function auto_title_insert( $value ) {
  if ( !$value ) :
    $value = $_POST['fields']['field_538626f57e84c'].' '.$_POST['fields']['field_538627ffeccb0'].' '.$_POST['fields']['field_53863a5c7502b'].' '.$_POST['fields']['fields[field_53a9bb09f82ba]'];
    return $value;
  endif;
  return $value;
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'auto_title_insert' );
```

The problem is, the title doesn't change when the custom post type is updated

Here's what I have for when the post is updated:

```
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    global $_POST;
    // vars
    $new_title = get_field('make', $post_id) . ' ' . $value;
    $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
    // update post
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post
      $my_post = array(
      'ID'              => $post_id,
      'post_title'      => $new_title,
      'post_name'       => $new_slug
  );
// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );   
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/make=make', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

The problem is I can only get it to work for one custom field instead of updating multiple fields

Here's what I have to make the title name the time stamp:

```
function auto_title_insert( $value ) {
  if ( !$value ) :
    $value = '['.get_the_date('d/m/Y @ H:i:s').']';
  endif;
  return $value;
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'auto_title_insert' );
```

That's ok, but I really want the post ID for organization

Comment: You are aware that you should sanitize stuff that you get from $_POST, right?

I hope you don't need this link - http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data, and you are showing some early PoC, that is soon to be made safe :)

Answer (score 2):

You could set it to the post ID when the post is first created via the `default_title` filter.

```
function wpd_default_title_filter( $post_title, $post ) {
    if( 'your_post_type' == $post->post_type ) {
        return $post->ID;
    }
    return $post_title;
}
add_filter( 'default_title', 'wpd_default_title_filter', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: That didn't work :/ I don't think it's possible to grab a post ID during the post creation. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @I_LOVE_WP sure it is, I've tested it. When you create a new post it immediately has an ID, so all the other stuff like custom fields and taxonomies have an ID to save data with. Make sure you change `your_post_type` to your actual post type slug in the example above.